# PHP Soap Client wrong version error with SOAP server returning correct response

Tags: php, laravel, soap, version, mismatch

I have a problem with SOAP request connecting to web service.

First, this is my code:

```
$soapClient = new NewSoapClient(null, [
        'location' =>
            "https://www.phobs.net/test/webservice/pc/service.php",
        'uri'      => "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05",
        'trace'    => 1,
        "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,
    ]);


    $ns_wsse = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';
    $password_type = 'ns2:http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText';

    // Creating WSS identification header using SimpleXML
    $root = new \SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');

    $security = $root->addChild('ns2:Security', null, $ns_wsse);

    $usernameToken = $security->addChild('ns2:UsernameToken', null, $ns_wsse);
    $usernameToken->addChild('ns2:Username', 'username', $ns_wsse);
    $usernameToken->addChild('ns2:Password', 'pass', $ns_wsse)->addAttribute('xsi:xsi:type', $password_type);
    $root->registerXPathNamespace('ns2', $ns_wsse);
    $full = $root->xpath('/root/ns2:Security');
    $auth = $full[0]->asXML();

    $auth = str_replace(' xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"','', $auth);

    $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(new \SoapHeader($ns_wsse, 'Security', new \SoapVar($auth, XSD_ANYXML), true));

    try {

        $response = $soapClient->__soapCall("OTA_RoomRateListRQ",[
            new \SoapVar('<ns1:HotelInfo HotelCode="' . 'ATL476' . '" DestinationSystemCode="' . 'ATLANTIS' . '" />', XSD_ANYXML)
        ]);

    } catch (\SoapFault $exception)
    {

        var_dump($exception);
        //die();
    }


    $response = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($soapClient->__getLastResponse())),1);
```

And I have wrapper around PHP's native Soap Client class:

```
class NewSoapClient extends \SoapClient
```

{

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
{

    $string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

    $request = str_replace($string , '', $request);

    $request = str_replace('xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"', 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"', $request);

    $request = str_replace('xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"', '', $request);

    $request = str_replace('xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >', 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">', $request);

    $request = trim($request);


    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

}

So basically it is connecting to SOAP web service (without WSDL) and it fetches some data. A lot of this code is here just to do string (or XML) manipulation so the request can look exactly as in the SOAP web service documentation. Final request (after all modifications) looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"
xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:Security>
        <ns2:UsernameToken>
            <ns2:Username>username</ns2:Username>
            <ns2:Password xsi:type="ns2:http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</ns2:Password>
        </ns2:UsernameToken>
    </ns2:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:OTA_RoomRateListRQ>
        <ns1:HotelInfo HotelCode="ATL476" DestinationSystemCode="ATLANTIS" />
    </ns1:OTA_RoomRateListRQ>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

So basically my request is the same as the request in documentation. When I trigger this code I get SoapFault exception with message "Wrong version" and fault code "VersionMismatch" and with faultcodens "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/".

Important thing to notice, if I wrap SOAP call in try/catch blocks and if I don't put any logic that is reacting to exception (leaving catch block empty), response will be returned with status code 200, and it will be parsed normally and my script will finish execution without any error.

Exception is definitely thrown, but if I don't react to it request lifecycle is completed successfully. What is the cause of this error? How to tackle this? Should I just leave catch block open without any logic? Is there a better solution?

Few more information about the system.
SOAP version is the same as in the documentation (1.1). My PHP version is 7.2, I don't have access to SOAP server so version running there is unknown...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT after resolution**: Be sure to check out the discussion in comments below my answer. It turned out that the service itself doesn't return SOAP, but XML, which causes the exception!

**Old answer**:

There's no way to query your service as you have not provided endpoint. Please do provide one if at all possible. It's also a good idea to see what happens if you use this request via `SOAPUI`, to make sure where the error actually comes from and rule out things one by one.

Otherwise my wild guess is that the service might now expect SOAP 1.2 version (without this being properly updated in the documentation in question) envelope and you are sending v 1.1 one, so you might try changing:

`xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`

to 
`xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"`

and see what happens. Worth a try...
A similar question has already [been discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660958/invalid-soap-message-or-soap-version-mismatch), look for more clues.

Comment: I am using Postman to test SOAP web service. As i stated previously SOAP request from documentation as well as from my script (request are identical), are valid, SOAP service is accepting them, I do get response with status code 200 (over Postman), so no problem there. So I started developing SOAP client in PHP and I managed to craft identical request using PHP Soap Client (code is above). When I fire requests from PHP Soap Client I actually do get correct response, it is just that PHP Soap Client throws VersionMismatch exception.

Comment: If I handle that exception, or just leave it empty (catch block) I am able to get response. Getting response is the last line in first snippet. 

So, the real question is why is PHP Soap Client throwing exceptions if request is passed and response is received?

I also tried changing version to SOAP1.2, in that case I don't get response, so it has to be SOAP1.1.

Here are details such as endpoint and complete request: https://pastebin.com/TWyp8RYN

I would be really glad if you can give it a look. Thx

Comment: Hi, @Andria, I don't have a full setup and cannot debug properly, but could you run wireshark in order to prove that what you're sending is indeed identical to what's being sent through Postman? I tried to play with the request provided and what I observed is that the response received is not fully valid SOAP, but plain xml. Could that be the issue and not the request itself?

Comment: Yes, the response is responsible for the error. PHP Soap Client expects valid SOAP response with envelope and other parts. Otherwise it will throw exception, as noted in PHP Soap internals: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php/blob/c233da1c5770a29f35e51606a1d6c726f6845dc6/php-src/ext/soap/php_packet_soap.c#L57

Thanks for pointing me in right direction.